# Error number 10170 using if/else and case statements

Tags: verilog

I am trying to compile the following code, but whenever I do, I get the errors:

'10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at FSM.v(9) near text "case"; expecting an operand'

'10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at FSM.v(9) near text ")"; epecting "<=" or "="'

'10170 Verilog HDL syntax error at FSM.v(11) near text "4"; expecting "end"'

```
module FSM (in0, in1, in2, in3, S, out0, out1, out2, out3); 
input in0, in1, in2, in3, S;
output out0, out1, out2, out3;
reg out0, out1, out2, out3;
always @(in0 or in1 or in2 or in3 or S)
begin
    if(S == 0) begin
    {
        case({in3, in2, in1, in0})
            4'b0000: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0000; //0->0
            4'b0001: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0011; //1->3
            4'b0010: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0110; //2->6
            4'b0011: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b1001; //3->9
            4'b0100: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0010; //4->2
            4'b0101: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0101; //5->5
            4'b0110: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b1000; //6->8
            4'b0111: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0001; //7->1
            4'b1000: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0100; //8->4
            4'b1001: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0111; //9->7
        endcase
    }
    end
    else begin
    {
        case({in3, in2, in1, in0})
            4'b0000: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0111; //0->7
            4'b0001: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b1000; //1->8
            4'b0010: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b1001; //2->9
            4'b0011: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0000; //3->0
            4'b0100: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0001; //4->1
            4'b0101: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0010; //5->2
            4'b0110: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0011; //6->3
            4'b0111: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0100; //7->4
            4'b1000: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0101; //8->5
            4'b1001: {out3, out2, out1, out0} = 4'b0110; //9->6
        endcase
    }
    end
end
endmodule
```

with the last error repeating for every line of code that's found in the `case` statements. If anyone has an idea of what I have wrong and how I could fix this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

**Remove the curly braces** (`{..}`) after `if` condition. Verilog is not C which requires curly braces, in Verilog, we use `begin..end` for multi-line procedural statements.

Also, the use of `always @(*)` (or `always_comb` in SystemVerilog) is recommended for **automatic sensitivity**, instead of manual sensitivity of `always @(in0 or in1 or in2 or in3 or S)`.

You might have to go through detailed Verilog syntax. Refer [Begin..end](http://www.electrosofts.com/verilog/beginend.html) link and [always sensitivity question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009998/verilog-always-block-using-symbol) for some of the information. Refer [IEEE 1364-2001](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/fa06/Labs/verilog-ieee.pdf) for Verilog and [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) for SystemVerilog.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you cannot use a concatenation operation as the argument for a case statement or on the left hand side of an assignment.

So you will need to do something like this:

```
....
reg [3:0] inword, outword;
begin
   inword = {in3, in2, in1, in0};
   if(S == 0) begin
      case (inword)
         4'b0000: outword = 4'b0000; //0->0
         ...
      endcase
   ...
   end
   out3 = outword[3];
   out2 = outword[2];
   out1 = outword[1];
   out0 = outword[0];      
end;
```

Comment: `case({in3, in2, in1, in0})` and `{out3, out2, out1, out0} = ...` are preferably legal syntax. Using intermediary variables to handle frequently concatenated signals is a good idea for reduced typing.